# Searchable Calendar Events solution

Tags: web-part, search, events

Morning

I'm using the Events Webpart on our intranet but I'm not finding it very usable. The big frustration is that if you choose to select 'All sites' as the Source and then click 'See all' when it's been published you effectively can't use the Category field unless you know the exact name of the category. Does anyone have a workaround or an alternative. The calendar view on a list is more searchable but unfortunately doesn't look pretty enough for our users.

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot customize the SharePoint default Events.aspx page as it is an application page.